# Qt Widget class' parent is always NULL

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have a custom `QWidget` class called `VideoWidget` that looks something like this:

```
VideoWidget::VideoWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    ClickableLabel *smallRed = new ClickableLabel(this)
    //...
    QObject::connect(smallRed,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(removeVideo()));
}
void VideoWidget::removeVideo(){
    //...remove a file
    MainWindow* myParent =  qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(this->parent());        
    QListWidget* myList = myParent->getList();
    QListWidgetItem* item = myList->currentItem();
    myList->removeItemWidget(item);
}
```

The `VideoWidget` widgets are created in my MainWindow class with the argument `this` and then added to a `QListWidget`. When clicking on the `smallRed` label in my `VideoWidget` I want my program to delete a file and then run the code to remove the widget from my `QListWidget` in my MainWindow. My problem is that the line `MainWindow* myParent =  qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(this->parent());` always returns NULL and I don't understand why. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: do you construct the `VideoWidget` instance by passing it the `this` pointer?

Comment: does dynamic_cast give you the right results?

Comment: `then added to a QListWidget` maybe QListWidget is a parent? It is empty words, just print it and see parent `qDebug() << parent();`

Comment: @Chernobyl No, the parent is not a QListWidget. I did debug it and `qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(this->parent())` is always returning NULL

Comment: You did not understand me, use only - `qDebug() << parent();` , not result of qobject_cast, who is a parent? QObject(0x00) or not?

Comment: @Chernobyl Ok, I'm getting `QWidget(0x1463b390, name = "qt_scrollarea_viewport")` as the output. I guess thats not my MainWindow. How can I get the MainWindow?

Comment: Don't do it like this, this design is horrible. Emit a signal from `VideoWidget` which tells that an item should be removed. Then connect this signal to a slot in your `MainWindow` which does the removing part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this code, I think you have something similar:

```
for(int r=0;r<2;r++)
{
    QListWidgetItem* lwi = new QListWidgetItem;
    ui->listWidget->addItem(lwi);
    ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(lwi, new QCheckBox(QString("checkBox%1").arg(r),this));
    qDebug() 
    << ui->listWidget->itemWidget(lwi)->parent()
    << ui->listWidget->itemWidget(lwi)->parent()->parent()
    << ui->listWidget->itemWidget(lwi)->parent()->parent()->parent()
    << ui->listWidget->itemWidget(lwi)->parent()->parent()->parent()->parent();
}
```

As you can see I set `this` as a parent, but my first parent is `qt_scrollarea_viewport` too, because Qt reparent your widget. Output of my code is:

```
QWidget(0x27c64260, name = "qt_scrollarea_viewport") 
QListWidget(0x27c64240, name = "listWidget") 
QWidget(0x264bedd8, name = "centralWidget") 
MainWindow(0x28fdcc, name = "MainWindow")
```

If you have same structure then use a few `parent()` calling

Yes, it is not very beautiful but as far as I know Qt has no something like `findParent`, only `findChildren`

As `thuga` suggested it works but it is not very good, your `VideoWidget` should not know about `MainWindow`. You should use signals and slots. Just emit signal from `VideoWidget` and catch this signal in `MainWindow` (write special slot and remove your item in this slot). It will be better than this magic with `parent()`.

Comment: Or he could just emit a signal which is connected to a slot in `MainWindow`. Then his class wouldn't need to know anything about `MainWindow`. This would be much better design, and it would avoid all the ugly code.

Comment: @thuga I totally agree with you, I don't like it too, but in my answer I wanted tI explain this parent-child feature, that we can set parent but Qt can reparent it in some conditions, so we should be careful with this.

Comment: You should still instruct the OP (and others who might encounter the same problem and end up looking for an answer here) to fix his design. Sometimes the best answer is not to give a solution to the problem that is being asked, but to tell the user why problems like that shouldn't even be problems in the first place.

Comment: @thuga the problem with that though is that my MainWindow doesn't know which Widget emited the signal. I will create a new question as the problem seems to be more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Widgets in QT are only automatically parented if you place them into a layout. Otherwise, if you create them without passing a parent pointer, they will be created without a parent, and will become a top-level window.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#QObject

Comment: I am pasing the parent as a pointer when I create them in my MainWindow. `VideoWidget* mytest = new VideoWidget(this);`